# Finding the inverse of an $N \times N$ matrix

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, inverse

I know that one easy way to find the inverse of a matrix is to reverse the two diagonal elements and change the sign of the two non-diagonal elements. Then if we divide by the determinant, we get the inverse matrix. **But I'm confused how to find the determinant of this matrix (below) and also confused about why they have moved the $\epsilon$ from denominator to numerator.**

Is there any easy way to find the inverse matrix?

Here is the matrix and its inverse matrix: 
[image]

Comment: Your recipe for inverting a matrix only works for $2 \times 2$ matrices... and you see it on the example you have given.

Comment: By the way, $D$ is the "discrete derivation" matrix and $D^{-1}$ is "discrete integration" matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of the large matrices filled with $\pm 1$'s is $1,$ because the determinant of a triangular matrix (matrix with all zeros either above or below the diagonal) is the product of diagonal entries. The $\epsilon$ is some unknown number that is applied to all the entries, i.e. your $\pm 1$'s are $\pm \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ in the first matrix, and the second matrix is all just $\epsilon$ nonzero entries. They have, then, "factored out" the $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\epsilon$ just as you would a constant term common to every element of a vector (or a common factor of every term of a polynomial, if you want an analogy).

To see why they wrote it with $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\epsilon,$ multiply the two matrices. The $\epsilon$ and $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ cancel (you can move "outside" scalars around in a matrix product) leaving you with just the $\pm 1$ matrix (lets call it $A$ for short) and the matrix with the lower left triangle full of $1's$ (let's call it $A^{-1}$ for short).

Now, multiply $A*A^{-1}.$ Remember, we canceled those confusing $\epsilon$ and $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ first.

What do we have? Well, the matrix $A$ tells you that, for row $1$ of the matrix its multiplying by on the left hand side, keep it the same (1 in the first column entry of row 1, zeros elsewhere).

The second row has $-1$ in the first column followed by $1$ in the second column This means to take the first row of the right hand matrix and subtract it off the second row, entry for entry, and re-record the second row with this result. That leaves you only with a $1$ in the second row, second column of the result.

The third row has a $0$ in the first column, $-1$ in the second column, and $1$ in the third column. This means, for the result's third row, you are to take the third row of $A^{-1},$ and add on the second row times $-1$ (i.e., subtract the second row from the third). That leaves us with a $1$ in the third row, third column of the result and zero elsewhere.

Continue in a like matter. What's your result?

Comment: Multiplying on the right by $A^{-1}$ tells you what to do with the *columns* of $A.$ to obtain your result. For instance, the first column of $A^{-1}$ is full of 1's. This means to take one copy of every column of $A$ and add them all together for the first column of the answer. Do it, and you see that all the entries have $1-1=0$ except for the first row entry, which is $1.$ For the second column, you have 1's except zero in the first row. That means take all columns except the first column of $A$ and add them for the second column of your answer (1 in second row, 0 elsewhere).